# Why 'ARABIC LETTER PEH' is not shown correctly on Android 3.x?

Tags: android, unicode, arabic, persian, farsi

[image]

In [Unicode characters](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html) the `ARABIC LETTER PEH INITIAL FORM` `'ﭘ'` is `0xFB58`. When I use the following code to show Unicode characters, **everything is OK for every Unicode character in Android 2.2, 2.3. and 4.x** But I have problem with `ARABIC LETTER PEH` `'ﭘ'` on **Android 3.x** and in this case character `'~'` is shown.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"TAHOMA.TTF");

strChars = "";
strChars += (char) 0xFB58;
tvChars.setTypeface(tf);
tvChars.setText(strChars);
```

I should mention that The problem is remained when I change the font or ignore using `setTypeface(tf)`

Why?

How can I find the code of `ARABIC LETTER PEH` in Unicode?

---

**EDIT:**

Please compare `0xFB58` (`ﭘ`) and `0xFB5E` (`ﭞ`) with any font programmatically. you will find the problem. the first one is not shown but the second one is shown correctly.

Comment: Do you want ARABIC LETTER PEH or ARABIC LETTER PEH INITIAL FORM?

Comment: both of them. both of them have problem.

Comment: Actually the problem is for:   0xFB56 (64342) and 0xFB57 (64343) and 0xFB58 (64344) and 0xFB59 (64345)

Comment: Sounds like your font doesn't have glyphs for characters in the Arabic Presentation Forms-A Block (starting at U+FB50).  I take it the regular ARABIC LETTER PEH (U+067E) shows fine?

Comment: "I should mention that The problem is remained when I ignore using my Unicode support font (tf)". When i ignore it and use the default font of Android 3.x all of Unicode characters are shown correctly except PEH.

Comment: Please check 0xFB56 and 0xFB5E with any font. you will find the problem. the first one is not shown but the second one is shown correctly.

Comment: Side-note: If you're talking about Unicode codepoints, then U+FB56 and U+FB5E is the clearest notation, as it's crystal clear that you're talking about Unicode codepoints here. 0xFB56 could be any hexadecimal  number.

Comment: I don't think you have the letter "Peh" in arabic. Try using Persian/Farsi.

Comment: **ARABIC LETTER PEH** is a standard name for Persian letter PEH.

Comment: You need a Farsi font. Arabic doesn't have `PEH`, its in Farsi and Urdu. You'll run into similar problems with other letters as well.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `1-` read the comment above your comment. `2-` go to http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html and `Ctrl+F` the `ARABIC LETTER PEH INITIAL FORM`. you will find that this is a standard name for this Persian letter. `3-` read my question and its samples completely.

Comment: As I said in my comment; its a font problem. Not a unicode problem. Your _font_ doesn't have a glyph for the unicode code point; which is why its not showing correctly. You'll get the same for `ARABIC LETTER TCHEH`, `ARABIC LETTER GAF` and others that are not part of Arabic. Just because its called _ARABIC LETTER_ doesn't mean it will be rendered by Arabic font. The Arabic alphabet is used in other languages, and your letter is not part of Arabic, but is rather part of Persian. If you have a Farsi or Urdu font installed, you will see the correct glyph rendered.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid this font shows other Persian letters like TCHEH and GAF correctly. also this font shows PEH correctly in Android 2.2 and 2.3. I am using this font in Android 2.2, 2.3, 3.x but I only have problem with PEH in Android 3.x. I have used other fonts but I had problem with PEH for all.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have this problem with both Tahoma and DroidSansFallback.ttf. I updated my question. Mention I am using Tahoma in Android 2.2 and 2.3 and it is OK with PEH in these versions of Android.

Comment: @breceivemail what about android4.x ?

Comment: @hasanghaforian It is OK in Android 4.x

Comment: @breceivemail It seems this is a bug.Are you agree?

Comment: @hasanghaforian Android 3.x supports Persian And when I do not use this code and use Persian letters directly in my code, it shows all of Persian letters correctly. I do not know what is the code of PEH in Android 3.x

Comment: @breceivemail It is strange.Your way to reshape words is basically correct.I had the same problem in `j2me` some years ago(that solved with an algorithm which use Unicode) and on `Android` in last year.I saw an App which it's name is `WikiVajeh` that support Persian in Android2+ and specially I tested it on android 3.0 .So it is possible to display it,`Do you guess any way to find it?Even testing any Unicode character!` Or Do you search in about other languages that may have the same problem?I tried this last night(2 hours) and did not find any useful thing.

Comment: In order to solve the problem for Android 3.x replace the first if clause in Farsi.Convert(String ) method with this: if (!isFarsiConversionNeeded || android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding your own fonts?

Get a Persian TTF font file that fits you and use it, this way you won't be OS dependent.
http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-how-to-use-true-type-fonts-ttf.html

Comment: look at my example and my picture and all of the content of my question

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but TAHOMA.TTF isn't a specific farsi font type. Did you try using a font that is specifically made for farsi?
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=farsi%20font%20ttf&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=803827a1757ecc6d&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1920&bih=965

Comment: TAHOMA.TTF supports Unicode. As I mentioned in the picture it shows all of Persian Unicode characters except PEH.

Comment: You mention a difference in behavior between devices, that's why I'm suggesting using your own fonts, to try and overcome this problem.